# vuejs3 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

hello i am a vuejs newbie, what i want to do actually looks simple but i couldn't figure it out.
when a member logs in
both
I want "Dashboard.vue" to be loaded as well as "home.vue" to be loaded, I've done it somehow, but
"http://localhost/home"
when i write
I get the following error.
how can i solve this?

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at pushWithRedirect
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import AdminRouter from './Admin/router';

    createApp(App)
        .use(AdminRouter )
        .use(store)
        .mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <main>
            <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
                <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                    <component :is="Component"/>
                </transition>
            </router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

router/index.js

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes.js'
import store from '../../store'
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if (store.getters.user) {
        if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.guard === 'guest')) next({name: 'admin'})
        else next();

    } else {
        if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.guard === 'auth')) next({name: 'login'})
        else next();
    }

})

export default router;
```

routes.js

```
export default [
    {
        path: "",
        component: () => import('../layout/Dashboard.vue'),
        name: 'admin',
        redirect: {name: 'home'},
        meta: {guard: 'auth'},
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                component: () => import('../Views/Home.vue'),
                name: "home",
                meta: {guard: 'auth'}
            },
            {
                path: "user",
                component: () => import('../Views/User/UserList.vue'),
                name: "user",
                meta: {guard: 'auth'}
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
        redirect: '/home',

    }
];
```

Comment: Shouldn't guest and auth be swapped? There is no "login". It redirects to "home" which is guarded with "auth"

Comment: Dashboard is the component where my header is navigation content and footer, so those who are not logged in cannot see it.
where is the mistake?

Comment: I see. Then this one - **There is no "login"**